# Issues with setting value with useState()

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am trying to implement video recording using React Webcam. Once a video is recorded, it should `setSelectedFile`. The `selectedFile` is then either uploaded to DB via `axios` post method or replaced by another recording. After each recording , the most recent should be available to view by the user.

The UI is working just as I want, showing the recoding screen during recording and the recorded file when recording has been complete.

My issue I am having is that the state value of my `selectedFile` (needed for posting via axios) is always 1 render behind what it should be. So after the first recording the `selectedFile` is undefined and after the second recording the file set as `selectedFile` is actually the first recording and so on. If I refresh the browser the entire process resets itself and starts the cycle again.

I have tried to call `setSelectedFile()` from a `useEffect` and without  `useEffect` (although if I understand useEffect correctly, I don't think I should need it here as I do not want this the be executed on each render). Either way it does not seem to make any difference to the behaviour of the program.

Am I doing something wrong with the `setSelectedFile` call. Like I said everything working fine apart from the selected file being 1 render (record/stop record) behind what it should be.

I attach my code below.

```
const RecordNow = () => {


     const[details, setDetails] = useState({consent:false, 
        idConfirmed:false, 
        label:"", 
        roundId:""})

    const {
        startRecording,
        stopRecording,
        mediaBlobUrl,
      } = useReactMediaRecorder({ video: true, audio: true, blobPropertyBag: {
        type: "video/mp4"
    } });

      const [curStatus, setCurStatus] = useState(true);
      const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState([null]);
      const [isFilePicked, setIsFilePicked] = useState(false);

      useEffect(()=>{
          setSelectedFile();
      },[])

      // Handles upload of selected file via axios
      const uploadToDB =()=>{
          console.log("Called")
          setDetails(prevDetails=>({
            ...prevDetails,
            consent:true,
            idConfirmed:true,
            label:"test_Label"
        }));

      axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP, details)
                     .then(res=>{
                         console.log("Res:", res)
                        const data = new FormData();

                        data.append("file", selectedFile)
                        console.log("SelectedFile", selectedFile)

                        axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP}}/file/upload`, data,
                        {
                            headers:{
                              "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"
                            }
                          })
                        .then(res=>{
                        console.log("Data: ",res.data)
                        console.log("success")
                })


                .catch((e)=>{
                    console.log("Error", e)
                })
                })
            }


        // Starts recording of new video
        const startedRec = () => {        
        startRecording();
        setIsFilePicked(false)
        setCurStatus(false);
    }


        // Stops recording of new video and creates blob
        const stoppedRec = async () => {
          stopRecording();
          const videoBlob = await fetch(mediaBlobUrl).then(r => r.blob());
          console.log("MediaBlob URL", mediaBlobUrl)
          const url = new Blob ([videoBlob]);

          //Creates a video file and filename
          const videoFile = new File([videoBlob], `wardround.${"mp4"}`, { type: "video/mp4" })

        console.log('Video File:', videoFile);
        console.log('Blob:', url);
            
        setSelectedFile(videoFile)
        console.log("Selected file", selectedFile)
        
        setCurStatus(true);
        setIsFilePicked(true)
        }

        // Handles input change and assigns input value to selectedFile variable
        const changeHandler = (event) => {
        setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
          setIsFilePicked(true);
          setDetails(prevDetails=>({
            ...prevDetails,
            consent:true,
            idConfirmed:true,
            label:"test_Label"
        }));
        };
    

      return (
        <div>
          {!isFilePicked ?
          <div className='player-wrapper'>
              <Webcam audio={false} height={400} width={500}/>
          </div> :
          <video height="400" width="500" controls>
              <source src={mediaBlobUrl}/>
           </video>
          }
          {curStatus ?
          <span>     
              <button id="video-record" onClick={startedRec}>Record Video</button>
          </span>  
          :
          <span>     
              <button id="video-record" onClick={stoppedRec}>Stop Recording</button>
          </span>  
          }
          {!isFilePicked ?
          <span>
            <label 
              className="file-upload"
              htmlFor="file-upload">
                UPLOAD VIDEO
            </label>
            <input 
              id="file-upload"
              type="file"
              onChange={changeHandler} 
            /> 
          </span> :
          <span>
            <label 
              className="file-upload"
              htmlFor="confirm-upload">
                SUBMIT VIDEO
            </label>
            <input 
              id="confirm-upload"
              type="submit"
              onClick={() => uploadToDB()}
            /> 
          </span>}
        </div>
      );
    };

export default RecordNow
```

Comment: give the right dependency to the useEfect, so it's getting updated on every change of that state

Comment: Whenever you see "1 render behind what it should be", remember that setting state is asynchronous. E.g. your `setSelectedFile(videoFile); console.log("Selected file", selectedFile)` cannot be expected to log the correct value, because that state change probably hasn't occurred yet.

Comment: @DBS. Ok. That makes sense. Could you suggest any way to allow for this 'state' change to have occurred before proceeding?

Comment: See my comment to @SlothOverlord answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State change occurs after console.log, so you always console .log the previous value.

The solution is to use useEffect or temp variables

useEffect

```
      useEffect(()=>{
          console.log(selectedFile);
      },[selectedFile]) //<< only console.log once selectedFile is changed
```

Temp values:

```
          //Creates a video file and filename
          const videoFile = new File([videoBlob], `wardround.${"mp4"}`, { type: "video/mp4" })

        console.log('Video File:', videoFile);
        console.log('Blob:', url);
            
        setSelectedFile(videoFile)
        //console.log("Selected file", selectedFile) <-- Wrong, stale data since setState is not finished jet.
        console.log("Selected file", videoFile) //<-- Use the data you are inserting into setSelectedFile to get to-be value.
```

Comment: So, I thought I had solved it with your help. Now I can see that the selectedFile details from the console.log within the useEffect is no longer is 'undefined' like it was when I console logged immediately after setSelectedFile(selectedFile). However the file contents still appear to be '1' render behind. That is, on initial 'record/stop' I can see an empty MP4 file which does not have the actual recording. This is only accessible after the second record/stop'. Any suggestions you might have would be great. Thanks

Comment: When I track further upstream, my stoppedRec function also seems to be behind. Despite it being called as async/wait the console.log(videoBlob) is of type 'text/html' after the first recording and then changes to 'video/mp4' (as expected) from the second  recording onwards.  `const stoppedRec = async () => {  
          stopRecording();  
          const videoBlob = await fetch(mediaBlobUrl).then(r => r.blob());  
          console.log("VideoBLOB", videoBlob)`